# Merging array objects with same properies

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

i am doing one of my front end project and i have a situation where i have to merge/add objects present in the array based on some conditions. Conditions would be

- Only those Objects having same label should be merged.
- For objects which has same label, if object 'a' has properties which are present in b object as well, the value has to be added, else simply copy the property.

So my input would be

```
[
  {
    label: 'label-1',
    published: 1,
    draft: 2,
    id: 'some1'
  },
  {
    label: 'label-1',
    published: 2,
    status: 0,
    draft: 1,
    id: 'some4'
  },
  {
    label: 'label-2',
    published: 1,
    draft: 14,
    id: 'some2'
  },
  {
    label: 'label-2',
    published: 12,
    status: 0,
    draft: 14,
    id: 'some3'
  }
]
```

and the expect

```
    [
      {
        label: 'label-1',
        published: 3,
        draft: 4,
        status: 0
      },
{
        label: 'label-2',
        published: 13,
        draft: 28,
        status: 0
      }
    ]
```

Currently i am using the following code for achieving the  same , but find it not tidy . Is there any way this could be achieved easily.

```js
function mapData(data) {
    let groupData = _.groupBy(data, 'label');
    let stackBarData = [];
    Object.keys(groupData).forEach((key) => {
      if (groupData[key] && groupData[key].length > 0) {
        let temp = Array.from(groupData[key]).reduce((a, b) => {
          for (let property in b) {
            if (b.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              if (property !== 'label' && property !== 'id' && property !== 'Others') {
                a[property] = (a[property] || 0) + b[property];
              } else {
                a[property] = b[property];
              }
            }
          }
          return a;
        }, {});
        stackBarData.push(temp);
      }
    });
    return stackBarData;
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: You have tagged both: underscore.js and lodash. These are 2 different libs. Which one are you using actually?

Comment: How is angular related to your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure ES6 function that collects the object values that are numeric, adding them up (which is what you seem to do), per unique label:

```js
function mapData(data) {
    const grouped = new Map(data.map( ({label}) => [label, { label }] ));
    for (let obj of data) {
        let target = grouped.get(obj.label);
        for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            if (typeof val === 'number') {
                target[key] = (target[key] || 0) + val;
            }
        }
    }
    return [...grouped.values()];
}

// Sample data
const data = [{label: 'label-1',published: 1,draft: 2,id: 'some1'},{label: 'label-1',published: 2,status: 0,draft: 1,id: 'some4'},{label: 'label-2',published: 1,draft: 14,id: 'some2'},{label: 'label-2',published: 12,status: 0,draft: 14,id: 'some3'}];

console.log(mapData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you have numeric properties that you wanted to exclude, then it might be better to have an explicit set of properties you are interested in:

```
const props = new Set(['status', 'published', 'draft']);
// ... etc
//
if (props.has(key)) { 
    target[key] = (target[key] || 0) + val;
}
// ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks .. just a doubt ...what exactly is happening in the first line of the code ? const grouped ....

Comment: It creates a Map from an array of key/value pairs. So the data is mapped to such key/value pairs and then provided to the Map constructor. Maps can only have unique keys, so it will create 2 Map entries for the example. Those two objects start out with only the label property (`{ label }` does that).

Answer (score 1):

**Lodash**

[`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) by the *label*, [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) the groups, and merge each group using [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith), and [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) the *id*. When merging the groups, if the current value is a number, sum the current and new values, if not return `undefined` - If customizer returns undefined, merging is handled by the method instead.

```js
const arr = [{"label":"label-1","published":1,"draft":2,"id":"some1"},{"label":"label-1","published":2,"status":0,"draft":1,"id":"some4"},{"label":"label-2","published":1,"draft":14,"id":"some2"},{"label":"label-2","published":12,"status":0,"draft":14,"id":"some3"}]

const result = _(arr)
  .groupBy('label')
  .map((g) => _.omit(_.mergeWith({}, ...g, (objValue, srcValue) => _.isNumber(objValue) ? objValue + srcValue : undefined), 'id'))
  .value()
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**ES6**

Iterate the array with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). On each iteration check if the accumulator (the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) the *label*, and if not add an empty object with the label as the key. Iterate the current object [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), ignore *id*, and sum the numeric values. To get an array spread the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```js
const arr = [{"label":"label-1","published":1,"draft":2,"id":"some1"},{"label":"label-1","published":2,"status":0,"draft":1,"id":"some4"},{"label":"label-2","published":1,"draft":14,"id":"some2"},{"label":"label-2","published":12,"status":0,"draft":14,"id":"some3"}]

const result = [...arr.reduce((m, o) => {
  m.has(o.label) || m.set(o.label, {})
  
  const obj = m.get(o.label)
  
  Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {
    if(k === 'id') return
    
    obj[k] = typeof o[k] === 'number' ? (obj[k] || 0) + o[k] : o[k]
  })
  
  return m
}, new Map()).values()]
  
console.log(result)
```