# Javascript - sum of JSON Array with respect to GoLive Date , i have a json array and wanted to calculate Sum and Cumulative Average

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following Dates:

```
var b = [
    {Date:'Jan 2016', steel:10.98},
    {Date:'Feb 2016', steel:5.67},
    {Date:'Jan 2016', steel:3.14},
    {Date:'Feb 2016', steel:2.14},
    {Date:'Mar 2016', steel:12.14}
]
```

I want to calculate both sum and cumulative average with respect to the dates shown above.

My desired output is:

Sum ->

```
[{"Date": "Jan 2016","val": 14.12},
{"date": "Feb 2016","val": 7.81},
{"date": "Mar 2016","val": 12.14}]
```

Cumulative Average ->

```
[{"Date": "Jan 2016","val": 7.06 },
{"date": "Feb 2016","val": 5.48},
{"date": "Mar 2016","val": 6.814}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging array objects with same properies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585817/merging-array-objects-with-same-properies)

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: That's an array of objects, no [JSON](http://json.org) involved.

Answer (score 0):

const sumSteelAndConcrete = (s = { steel: 0 }, c = { steel: 1 }) => s.steel + c.steel;
const findByDate = (arr, date) => arr.find(item => item.Date === date);

const result = dates.map(
    sumSteelAndConcrete(
      findByDate(steelDays, date),
      findByDate(steelDays, date)
    )
  )
);

Comment: What is this? The answer? if is this your try code, add it in an edit to the question, not as an aswer